# find the same part in a string

Tags: python, genome

I have a string such as : abcgdfabc

I want to do like following:
input: a string, e.g.:

```
abcgdfabc
```

output: a dict (key is the "words",and value is the time it shows up),

```
abc:2
gdf:1
```

words is the maxmium lenght of "words", it should be greedy match.

I have spent a lot time on it, and can't figure out.
The string is longer than 5000, it's a genome, we want to find out the relationship of it, the first time we have to find such a dict to make data more clear, help.

Comment: How should we know "gdf" is a word if it appears once only? Aren't "g" and "df" words too?

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to do with this genome? (Also, are you aware of [Biostar](http://www.biostars.org)? (SE-format bioinformatics site)

Comment: Are the keys/words you want to count fixed?

Comment: if the 'words' appears just once,we use greedy match to regard it as a words.

Comment: what about input 'abcgdfabceabcg', should the solution take 'abc':3 as a word or 'abcg': 2 as a word?

Comment: adcg as a word,the same part,use greedy match to match a word.

Answer (score 2):

This regex looks for groups of alphanumerics, followed optionally by any number of other characters and then again by itself. Then it iterates over this list with duplicates removed and gives you these groups of characters and the number of their occurence:

```
import re

s = "eg,abcgdfabc"
for word in set(re.findall(r'(\w+)(\w*?\1)+', s)):
    print word, s.count(word)
```

prints

```
abc 2
```

However, if we don't know exactly what a word is, then it will find just one repeating word in the following string, although there is another candidate:

```
abcdeabcecd
abc  abc    <- this will be found
  cd     cd <- this won't be found
```

Comment: it seemed the code can't work well,I got error like:    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly solution:

```
def parse(s,L=None):
    do_return=L is None
    if(not s):
        return
    if(do_return):
        L=[]
    substr=s[0]
    for i in range(1,len(s)-1):
        if s[:i] in s[i:]:
            substr=s[:i]
        else:
            L.append(substr)
            parse(s.replace(substr,''),L=L)
            break
    else:
        L.append(s)

    if(do_return):
        LL=[(ss,s.count(ss)) for ss in L] #Count the number of times each substring appears
        LLL=[]
        #Now some of our (unmatched) substrings will be adjacent to each other.
        #We should merge all adjacent unmatched strings together.
        while LL:
            LLL.append(LL.pop(0))
            while LLL[-1][1] == 1 and LL: #check if next is unmatched
                if(LL[0][1]==1): #unmatched, merge and remove
                    LLL[-1]=(LLL[-1][0]+LL[0][0],1)
                    LL.pop(0)
                else: #matched, keep on going.
                    break
        d={}
        for k,v in LLL:
            d[k]=v

        return d


S='eg,abcgdfabc'
print parse(S)  #{ 'e':1, 'g':2, ',':1, 'abc': 2, 'df', 1}
```

Of course, this doesn't work quite like you expect because g matches twice (since it is greedy) ...

If you always want to iterate through in groups of 3, this become a lot easier (and prettier):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def parse(s,stride=3):
    d=defaultdict(lambda:0)
    while s:
        key=s[:stride]
        d[key]+=1
        s=s[stride:]

    #if you need a regular dictionary:  dd={}; dd.update(d); return dd      
    return d
```

Comment: +1 for the effort in writing the long version out, with comments. I would +2 for the _ugly_ part if I could.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid -- Thanks.  I'm sure I could make this a little nicer if I was motivated enough -- (Some of the logic in the indexing gets a little messy there).  If we can step through the string 3 elements at a time and just use that chunk, the problem gets a lot easier (Like your very nice example using `Counter`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Python 2.7+

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def split_steps(step, sequence):
...    it = iter(sequence)
...    bits = ''.join(islice(it,step))
...    while bits:
...        yield bits
...        bits = ''.join(islice(it,step))
...
>>> Counter(split_steps(3,'abcdgfabc')).most_common()
[('abc', 2), ('dgf', 1)]
```